# Valor de HiddenField sempre nulo

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Bom dia, estou a aprender asp.net e deparei-me com um problema no meu código que não sei como resolver. Eu tenho uma gridview que é alimentada pela base de dados e tenho um botão que chama o evento Rowdeleting e estou a tentar pegar o valor do HiddenField da mesma row onde esse evento foi chamado, desculpem se ficou confuso se não entenderem posso tentar explicar melhor.

**Este é o meu código:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No data available" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" CssClass="table table-bordered">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">  
            <ItemTemplate>                                      
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Role" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Role") %>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:Label>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
            <EditItemTemplate>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Role" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Role") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
            </EditItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:CommandField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="5" EditText="<img class='img-fluid' style='min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;' src='imagens/edit.svg'>" ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="5" DeleteText="<img class='img-fluid' style='min-width: 20px; max-width: 20px;' src='imagens/recyclebin-512.png'>" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string _id = "";
    int _index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (_index == row.RowIndex)
        {
            _id = row.Cells[0].Text;
        }
    }

    DataTable dt = _sql.GetEditRoles();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

O valor que está vindo vazio é o _id.

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o `.Text` não irá obter valor de um hidden field.

Uma alternativa é usar essa coluna como um DataKey.

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="id" ...
```

No evento precisa utilizar:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    var key = this.GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Ronaldo!

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o valor do `HiddenField` precisa ir pela propriedade `Value`:

```
if (_index == row.RowIndex)
{
    _id = ((HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("hiddenid")).Value;
}
```